# How to detect environment in a Cordova android application?

Tags: android, cordova

I am using `Cordova` + `ReactJS` + `Redux` in my android application. Redux logger middleware is a great way for logging redux store state for every action. But it also introduces performance issues when you run them in your mobile app. So I am looking for a way to `enable/disable` the log by detecting the environment. This logic should happen when it creates redux state store.

Below is the code to build the android apk in dev and release mode:

dev: `cordova build android --debug -- --buildConfig config/build.json`

release: `cordova build android --release -- --buildConfig config/build.json`

Is there a way to check whether this is `debug` or `release`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`cordova-plugin-is-debug`](https://github.com/mattlewis92/cordova-plugin-is-debug) to detect if build is debug or not and control your logs accordingly. It will work for Android and iOS both.

**Install**:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-is-debug
```

**Usage**:

```
cordova.plugins.IsDebug.getIsDebug(function(isDebug) {
  console.log('Is debug:', isDebug);
  if (isDebug) {
    //Debug build
  } else {
    //Release build
  }
}, function(err) {
  console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wonder how to import them. I got an error if I do `import cordova, {isDebug} from 'cordova-plugin-is-debug'`